# Debug portal_skins order for Dexterity content types

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

We have one Plone site (4.3.x) using TinyMCE version 1.4.3, but we found that we should have the version 1.3.18 instead for this Plone version.

So I:

- Uninstalled the TinyMCE package ( manage / portal_setup / import / Remove TinyMCE profile ).
- Pin buildout version to 1.3.18 and run buildout.
- Reinstalled TinyMCE package ( same procediment, but select TinyMCE install profile).

After that I notice that:

- For default Plone content types it worked fine.
- For the new dexterity content types defined in this Plone Site it didn't work.  It load just a textarea with html into it instead of load TinyMCE.

I did many tests on this, and what I can see is that my content type should use `wysiwygEditorBox` macro from this template `Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tinymce_wysiwyg_support.pt` but instead it is using this template `Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_wysiwyg/wysiwyg_support.pt`.

I tried to change order of `portal_skins` but it just affect Archetypes types, not Dexterity types.

What step should I do next? is there any better way to debug it instead of adding `<span>` tags with debug messages?

Comment: Check for JavaScript error in the JS console.

Comment: there are no erros.. in fact the css class ``mce_editable`` is not being loaded into the textarea, so the JavaScript is not being loaded (just for dexterity content type).

Comment: Just to be sure that is an issue of this portal: if you create a *new* Plone site in the same database/instance, are TinyMCE + Dexterity working properly?

Comment: yes, it works.  We find what was the problem thanks to @djowett the uninstall profile of tinymce created the problem here https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/issues/136 I'm waiting his answer here in S.O. to accept as right answer :) thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the `parts/omelette` directory shows the following in `plone/app/form/widgets/wysiwygwidget.pt (line 21)`

```
support_path       string:nocall:here/${editor}_wysiwyg_support|here/${editor}/wysiwyg_support|here/po
```

My guess is that `${editor}` isn't set right (ie to tinymce) so the above line is falling back to search for the `wysiwyg_support.pt` template.

Comment: Thanks @danimal , your guess make us understand what was going on here, and we finally found the [real problem in TinyMCE uninstall profile](https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/issues/136).